# Showing associativity holds over n elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, logic

Say we have a set $X$, with an associative binary operator $*$. How can we show that for any string $x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n$, when we insert brackets or the operation $*$, we will always get the same output?

Clearly this requires induction on $n$. The base case $n=1$ is trivial, but I cannot figure out how to move from my induction hypothesis, that the claim holds for strings of length less than $n$, to the fact that it holds for strings of length $n$.

The issue is that when I start with a string of length $n-1$, for example, there are so many ways to add the $x_n$ that I get lost. I think I need to split the string of length $n$ into small ones of lengths less than $n$ but I cannot figure out how to account for all possible forms of the string.

Thanks!

Comment: Would strong induction work better than weak induction here?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you need, but Maclane's Coherence theorem is relevant (though it's somewhat of an overkill). You could look up the combinatorial proof of the theorem, which you can probably adapt to the simpler setting.

Comment: Tony, strong induction would help, it's what I was getting at with splitting the string into smaller ones, each with length less than $n$ (but not necessarily $n-1$). But where is the correct place to split?

Comment: If you use strong induction, it shouldn't matter where you split. A string of length $n$ will split into strings of lengths $k$ and $n-k$, both of which are less than $n$, and therefore covered by the strong induction hypothesis. I think that works, anyway.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs But how do you justify that when $k=1$, we get the same result as when $k = n-1$ ?

Comment: @ChasBrown, that's not clear to me. It depends what you mean by "it". What exactly would the induction hypothesis be here, and how exactly does it connect to the $n+1$ case? It's not clear to me that it doesn't work, although I don't have to details worked out as to how it does work either.

Comment: @Tony We need to use the fact that $(a \cdot b) \cdot c = a \cdot (b \cdot c)$; there is a shared span in the two cases I described which could take on the role of $b$.

Comment: I'm a little bit lost in this discussion. Chas, are you aware of how to do it and giving hints or just pointing out the problem with G Tony Jacob's solution?

Comment: Hinting; think of how we might assert that $(abcd)(ef) = (a)(bcdef)$ by observing that $(abcd)(ef) = ((a)(bcd))(ef) = (a)((bcd)(ef)) = (a)(bcdef)$; and from that we then generalize that $(abcdef)$ is well-defined. It's late here; I'll post an answer tomorrow if no one else has.

Comment: I think I have it! Please don't post an answer for a little bit, I will write mine up in about an hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Claim:**

> Any string including $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ as above is equal to 
>   $$x = x_1 * (x_2 * ( \ldots *  (x_{n-1} * x_n ) \ldots ))) \in X$$

**Proof:**

Proceed by induction on $n$. The base case $n=1$ is trivial. Assume the above claim holds when the length is $k < n$.

Let $\phi$ be any such string of length $n$ that evaluates to $a \in X$. Then $\phi$ can be uniquely written as the * product of two shorter strings. Note that for expressions of length less than $n$, we will write simply $(x_1 x_2 \ldots x_l)$ because of the associativity guaranteed by the induction hypothesis. So:

$$\phi = (x_1 x_2 \ldots x_k) * (x_k x_{k+1} \ldots x_n)$$

And we can move the * all the way to the left by using associativity of three elements:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\phi \, &= (x_1 x_2 \ldots x_k) * (x_{k+1} \ldots x_n) \\
&= ((x_1 x_2 \ldots x_{k-1}) * x_k) * (x_{k+1} \ldots x_n) \\
&= (x_1 x_2 \ldots x_{k-1}) * (x_k x_{k+1} \ldots x_n) \\
&= ((x_1 x_2 \ldots x_{k-2}) * x_{k-1}) * (x_k \ldots x_n) \\
&= (x_1 x_2 \ldots x_{k-2}) * (x_{k-1} x_k \ldots x_n)
\end{aligned}
$$

and eventually

$$\phi = x_1 * (x_2 x_3 \ldots x_n)$$

which has the form

$$x = x_1 * (x_2 * ( \ldots *  (x_{n-1} * x_n ) \ldots ))) \in X$$

Comment: Looks good to me!